# SQL Server: How to customize Merge When Matched area

Tags: t-sql

See my code where I insert or update a table from XML using merge statement.

```
drop table if exists Student
       
  Declare @Data xml  
             
   set @Data=  
   '<Root>  
   <Student>  
   <Name>Rakesh</Name>  
   <Marks>80</Marks>  
   </Student>  
   <Student>  
   <Name>Mahesh</Name>  
   <Marks>90</Marks>  
   </Student>  
   <Student>  
   <Name>Gowtham</Name>  
   <Marks>60</Marks>  
   </Student>  
   <Student>  
   <Name>Manoj</Name>  
   <Marks></Marks>  
   </Student>  
   </Root>'  
         
    create table Student (
    Name varchar(10),
    Marks int
    )
       
    insert into Student values
    ('Rakesh',90),
    ('Mahesh',80),
    ('Jack',80),
    ('Manoj',57)
       
  DECLARE @archive TABLE
  (
     ActionType  varchar(10),
     Name varchar(10),
     Marks int
  );
       
   Merge into Student as Trg  
   Using (select d.x.value('Name[1]','varchar(20)') as Name ,  
   d.x.value('Marks[1]','int') as Marks from  
   @data.nodes('/Root/Student')as d(x)) as Src  
   on Trg.Name=Src.Name  
   When Matched Then update set  
   Trg.Marks=Src.Marks  
   when not matched  then  
   insert (Name,Marks) values (Src.Name,Src.Marks)
   OUTPUT
     $action ,
     inserted.*
  INTO @archive;
```

I want when Name **match** then UPDATE will perform but **when Name match but Marks is empty** then that records will be deleted based on name matched.

so tell me how could I customize this.

see my XML there is one student named **Manoj** whose marks are empty then that records will be removed from the table based on name matched.

**How could I mention a condition in Merge that when Name matched and marks not empty then update and when Name matched but marks are empty then that records will be removed from the table.**

Can i use Multiple matched condition ? if yes then it will be possible.

please guide me on how to achieve this. thanks

Comment: It can do deletes. You just put `DELETE` in for the operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use multiple `WHEN MATCHED` parts each with a clause search condition. One search checks that Src.Marks is not zero and the other checks that it was.

I've also put a clause search condition on the `NOT MATCHED` part as I would guess you don't want to be inserting people that have no marks either.

```
MERGE INTO Student as Trg  
USING (
    SELECT 
        d.x.value('Name[1]','varchar(20)') AS Name ,  
        d.x.value('Marks[1]','int') AS Marks 
    FROM  
        @data.nodes('/Root/Student') AS d(x)
) AS Src  
ON Trg.Name=Src.Name  
WHEN MATCHED AND Src.Marks <> 0 THEN 
    UPDATE 
    SET  
        Trg.Marks=Src.Marks  
WHEN MATCHED AND Src.Marks = 0 THEN
    DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND Src.Marks <> 0 THEN  
   INSERT (Name,Marks) 
   VALUES (Src.Name,Src.Marks)
   OUTPUT
     $action,
     inserted.*
  INTO @archive;
```

Comment: Sir when match found then can i update / insert data into another tables from there ? see a sample code. see and tell me does it work ? 

`MERGE INTO Student as Trg  
USING (
 Select * from T1
) AS Src  
ON Trg.Name=Src.Name  
WHEN MATCHED AND Src.Marks <> 0 THEN 
    UPDATE 
    SET  
    Trg.Marks=Src.Marks  
 
 UPDATE AnotherTable1 SET col=val1 where
 
 INSERT AnotherTable2(col1,col2) values ('a','b')
WHEN MATCHED AND Src.Marks = 0 THEN
    DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND Src.Marks <> 0 THEN  
   INSERT (Name,Marks) 
   VALUES (Src.Name,Src.Marks)
`

Comment: Can you please tell me what kind of lock sql server place on table when we insert data `Insert into table1(....)` with in Begin Tran & Commit Tran ?